# how to change the text value in a textview, whilst in a fragment. Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments

Does anyone know of a way to change the value of a textview text, whilst in a fragment. I have tried findviewbyid, however i believe that this does not work whilst in a fragement. Does anyone have an idea on how to identify a textview and change the text value of it. Thanks

```
class Home : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(

        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(view.context)
        val url = "https://io.adafruit.com/api/v2/alex9301/feeds/test-data/data" //URL
        var urlStuff = ""

        val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            { response ->
                // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                urlStuff = response
                val jsonArray = JSONTokener(urlStuff).nextValue() as JSONArray
                val id = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("value") // Get data
                Log.i("Val: ", id)

                //Updating info on app
                val textView = view.findViewById(R.id.temp)                 
                textView.text = "My Text"


            },
            { Log.i("b", "That didn't work!") })
        queue.add(stringRequest)
        return view

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

findViewById also works in a fragment, like this:

```
val view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
val textView: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.temp)
textView.text = "My Text"
```

Comment: Hi, when i try adding this to my program like so
```val textView = view.findViewById(R.id.temp)
                textView.text = "My Text"``` findviewbyid is still underlined with red?

Comment: Can you add that code in your question?

Comment: I copied your code. view.findViewById is not red here. I have added `: TextView` to the second line, I forgot it at first.